# network programming in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming

I'm looking for some good resources about network programming in .NET (c# preferably), I managed to find out few e-books but they are all the books back in 2002-2003.
If you know any e-book, video, websites ...   or any other resources will be thanks full to comment them for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what level of abstraction you're looking for. If you're interested in higher-level network development, look at the [WCF Beginner's Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/first-steps-with-wcf.aspx).

Comment: My main focus is on remote application programming.

Comment: Here are few of the tasks I'm usually work on,It may help to give you an overview:
1-secure file transferring (both over LAN & WAN)
2-Remote access (both to a specific software on remote machine or entire OS);

Answer (score 2):

"[Network Programming in .Net](http://www.webtropy.com/)" is the best book I've read on the subject, and most of it is still quite relevant. The things that it would leave out are Sockets (in v2.0, although it does cover the concept) and the WCF stack, both of which can be covered by other material.

Comment: This is the book I found it few days ago, and i red some parts too,Its a good book man, but since it works with pre versions of .NET do you have any comment that which parts may have changed in newer versions, I know its a heavy book and u don't remember it all, but i just need a clue.

Comment: There isn't much changed from v1.1 (which the book covers) to v4.0 as far as the network stack is concerned. Of course, in v2.0, Socket support was added, and in v3.0 WCF joined the fray, but these subjects would likely just be supplemental chapters in that book, and readings on them can be found elsewhere. System.Network.Dns also got a makeover in v2.0, from what I remember, and this is well documented in MSDN.

Comment: I'm reading Network Programming in .Net currently and I would not recommend it because the example codes in the book are poorly written and I'm considering to leave it because I'm so annoyed with the author's negligence.

Answer (score 2):

The best book I've read is [C# Network Programming.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0782141765)  In my opinion the best way to learn network programming is to pick one of the many examples off codeproject (like [tcp chat](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/TCPIPChat.aspx)) and review the code.  Many of the core concepts like TCP, UDP, Berkley Sockets, etc have been around way before C# came about and cross the boundries of programmer and admin (which just happens to be one of my favorite things to do).

Comment: Brian, Is it update to date and actually using built-in API like HttpClient (async implementation) for all GET, POST requests including file uploads, downloads (multipart-form) etc. I'm looking for comprehensive guide without brining any 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/C-Sharp/Socket-Programming-in-C-Part-I/1/

is a resource I've used. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need information on bare-bones TCP communication using the `Socket` class, [I have a FAQ on the subject](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html) geared towards people not familiar with TCP/IP.

You may want to start off with a higher-level technology, though, such as WCF.